# Add missing keys to `dict` in `list`

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So, I need to plot something with matplotlib, and all was going perfect up until this error. Basically, what I need is to turn the following:

```
[
  {
    "foo":1,
    "bar":2
  },
  {
    "foo":8,
    "baz":3
  }
]
```

into something like this:

```
[
  {
    "foo":1,
    "bar":2,
    "baz":0
  },
  {
    "foo":8,
    "baz":3,
    "bar":0
  }
]
```

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: You can use a `defaultdict` with `int` since this will return `0` for keys that don't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we're posting answers... There's an easier way. Simply turn your dicts into `defaultdict`s wherever it is that you're defining them. - `defaultdict(int, your_dictionary)`

You can then access this dict for your plot regardless of non-existent keys since if they don't exist the defaultdict will just return 0 here as you want. No point reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: While this answer has helped OP, it's worth pointing out the behaviour will be different to OP's desired output, where you will get a `KeyError` if a key is queried which does not exist. Whether this works with `matplotlib` [the end use] should be confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to calculate the union of your keys and then iterate via a `for` loop.

```
keys = set().union(*lst)

for d in lst:
    for k in keys - d.keys():
        d[k] = 0

print(lst)

[{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 0},
 {'foo': 8, 'baz': 3, 'bar': 0}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If `keys` is the list of keys and `L` is the list of dictionaries then:

```
for d in L:
    for k in keys:
        d.setdefault(k, 0)
```

sets each missing key to `0`.